# Select 2 columns of an HTML table based on the first column selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with like 7 columns. When I select a column I want all the other columns to be hidden except the column next to the selected one. To be clear, only 2 columns need to be visible at a time - and those are the one selected and the one next to it. If there is a column to the right of the selected column, this one should be shown along with the selected column, if not (last column selected) the column to the left shall be shown along with the selected one.

I tried using loops but the problem is the user can select any column from the table.

My code:

```
    var I = document.getElementsByTagName("th").length;
    if(s=== I-1) { // s - index of selected column- check if its the last column
        for (var D = 0; D < I-2; D++) {
            var o = datatable.column(D);
            o.visible(!o.visible());
        }
    } else {
        for (var D = 0; D < s; D++) {                            
            var o = datatable.column(D);
            o.visible(!o.visible());
        }

        for (var D = s+1; D < I; D++) {                         
            var o = datatable.column(D);
            o.visible(!o.visible());               
        }
   }
```

My HTML:

```
<table id="DataTables_Table_0" >
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
            <th>
                <div>Pro</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Pri</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>State</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>phyId</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Title</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Origin</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>type</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="">
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="0 sorting_1">Private</td>
            <td class="1">High</td>
            <td class="2">Create</td>
            <td class="3">E210DC29509F</td>
            <td class="4">5</td>
            <td class="5">8/9/2019, 8:24:00 AM</td>
            <td class="6">Issue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="0 sorting_1">Public</td>
            <td class="1">Low</td>
            <td class="2">Assign</td>
            <td class="3">E210DC29509F</td>
            <td class="4">5</td>
            <td class="5">8/9/2019, 9:11:11 AM</td>
            <td class="6">Issue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="0 sorting_1">Private</td>
            <td class="1">Medium</td>
            <td class="2">Assign</td>
            <td class="3">E210DC29509F</td>
            <td class="4">5</td>
            <td class="5">8/9/2019, 9:17:26 AM</td>
            <td class="6">Issue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="0 sorting_1">Public</td>
            <td class="1">Urgent</td>
            <td class="2">Active</td>
            <td class="3">E210DC29509F</td>
            <td class="4">5</td>
            <td class="5">8/8/2019, 4:14:59 PM</td>
            <td class="6">Issue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

An update to the question: I can select the 1st column always alonwith the column selected by the user. So that means I dont have to manually select the adjacent column from the table. I just modified the code:

```
for (var D = 1; D < I/2 ; D++) { 
                            if (D !== s ) {
                                var o = f.datatable.column(D);
                                o.visible(!o.visible());
                            }
                        }
```

Now it works as expected. Actually this was for generating a line chart for the table data. Now i get a line chart, but i am just confused as to if the line chart does look as expected. I mean I have attached a screenshot of my line chart, but it looks like ther is something more to do. Sorry for not mentioning about the line chart as i thought it would make the question more complicated and confusing.[linechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztqov.jpg) [tabledata for the line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogppI.jpg)

How exactly should a line chart look with my table.

Comment: provide the html and code you have tried.

Comment: You're gonna need to include your HTML and JavaScript, and also more details. For example, when you say "*the column next to the selected one*" do you mean to the right? To the left? Either?

Comment: I have updated the HTML and code in the question. And the column next can be the one to the right; But if selected column if the last one then need the left column.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What exactly does it fail to do -- select the correct columns, hide the columns, etc.?

Comment: It works fine if the selected column is the last one. but if it falls somewhere in the middle, it doesnot select the next one, instead jumps to the one after the intended column- skips the column which i need to be selected. I would want a  more clean and better code which can handle both situation- whether the selected column is last or middle.

Comment: You're apparently using some kind of library for your tables as there is no native method `datatable.column(D);`... Please include what library that is.

Answer (score 0):

I would make those td class names more explicit, so they're clearly labeling columns (like `col-0`), and then query the DOM based on those.

On selection change:

1. Hide all the columns.
2. Get the index being selected.
3. Calculate the two column class names to show.
4. Query for those class names and show those DOM nodes.

Here's some (untested) example js:

```
$('th, td').hide();
// for the OP: make sure colIndex isn't the rightmost col
const selectedCol = 'col-' + colIndex; 
const nextCol = 'col-' + (colIndex + 1);
$('.' + selectedCol).show();
$('.' + nextCol).show();
```

Comment: How can this be achieved  through javascript

Comment: That is javascript. You had already posted similar on-select code, so I thought you were already at that point. The `$` is jQuery.

Comment: There's no jQuery in OP's code, nor is the question tagged with it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the count of all columns.
then hide all the columns.
and then only show the selected and next or previous column

```js
var I = document.getElementsByTagName("th").length;

function hideCol(s){
    datatable.columns( 'th' ).visible( false );
    if(s == I-1){
        datatable.column(s).visible(true);
        datatable.column(s-1).visible(true);
    }else if(s < I){
        datatable.column(s).visible(true);
        datatable.column(s+1).visible(true);
    }
}

hideCol(2);
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in OP's code, nor is the question tagged with it.